# ElasticSearch xcontent for unknown value of type class java.math.BigInteger

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created the index with the following mapping in elasticsearch:

```
PUT my_master
{
    "mappings": {
        "documents": {
            "properties": {
                "fields": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "uid": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "copy_to": "fulltext",

                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 32766
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "fulltext": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Added a document into it:

```
POST my_master/documents/1/_create
{

   "fields": [

            {
              "uid": "number",
              "value": 111111111111111000000000000001100000000000000
            }
          ]

}
```

After adding I am using update API to update document :

```
POST my_master/documents/1/_update
{
"doc":{
   "fields": [

            {
              "uid": "number",
              "value": 1111111111111110000000000000011000000000000000
            }
          ]

}}
```

But elasticsearch gives me following error while updating the document:

```
cannot write xcontent for unknown value of type class java.math.BigInteger
```

Please help me here? What is wrong here? How to solve this issue?

Comment: What happens if you enclose your number inside double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

according to the mapping i would expect that you send the value as a string, therefore i think this might work:
"1111111111111110000000000000011000000000000000"